# Webpack watch file changes and trigger loader for other files

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel-loader

I'm looking for a way to watch changes on files (sass files precisely) and execute a loader on other files (js files) with webpack.

The goal is to detect sass changes and recompiling all the javascript files with the babel-loader, because they might import it through the styled-jsx plugin.

I'm stuck in the "loader" concept and can't figure out how to get other files when testing for /.scss$/

Comment: Did you ever come up wit ha solution to this issue?

Comment: Nope sorry :/ I switched to VueJS which handles everything through its vue-loader instead and does the re-render i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything by yourself if you using scss modules with webpack (more about `module` concept in the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/modules/).

What webpack does - it starts at entry point (you can specify one or multiple entrypoints, if you don't, default `src/index.js` would be used). And then builds dependency trees between modules (which can have any file extension as long as there's a specific loader that can turn file into module). Webpack then watches all files and rebuild all modules that have a dependency on changed file. So, if you import the .scss file in, let's say, your entrypoint

```
import './styles.scss';
// ...
```

It would rebuild automatically when `styles.scss` changes

Comment: Thanks for your answer eldarg! The problem is that I don't want to create redundancy in the generated css, and from what I can understand, importing './anything.css' in my js with every other modules AND having it imported though css-in-js plugin "styled-jsx" from Zeit would probably import it twice. Am I right in this supposition?

Comment: Also this solution would trigger the sass loader and not the babel loader used by the js files if I'm not wrong. So it doesn't re-render those files through the css-in-js... :/

Comment: `styled-jsx` written in javascript files, which are already processed by `babel-loader` and updates on changes if webpack is run in with `--watch` option.

Comment: PS. i see, you use styled-jsx with sass's includePaths option. In this case there is no good way to use @import in styled-jsx. You can try [webpack-watch-files-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-watch-files-plugin), but this would trigger full rebuild each time these files changes, not only the files that needs to be changed

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your `.scss` file(s) under one of your `.js` files so that webpack actually picks up the changes.

Then, all loaders you have configured will be applied automatically based on which file type they should target.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sergio! As I said to Eldarg just above, the problem is that I don't want to create redundancy in the generated css, and from what I can understand, importing './anything.css' in my js with every other modules AND having it imported though css-in-js plugin "styled-jsx" from Zeit would probably import it twice. Am I right in this supposition?

Comment: Also this solution would trigger the sass loader and not the babel loader used by the js files if I'm not wrong. So it doesn't re-render those files through the css-in-js... :/

Comment: Okay I got you now, Could you share some code, I think that would help see how we can fix this

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the babel-plugin won't import anything for you it merely tells babel how to transpile  `<style jsx>` tags

Comment: Sharing the real code would be difficult because it's kinda massive already, but I can give you a fiddle with the idea! https://jsfiddle.net/regzwnd0/ this is a classic component with some explanation in the js comments and this is my webpack config https://gist.github.com/kvinlambert/3c75d4dd9c0ecc075476ea9015132a14 
Thanks a lot for the help Sergio ;)